# Phonegap autogenerates code for new platform?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am a new bee to phonegap and want to clarify some doubts .

I have heard that phone gap allows you to code for one platform and then code for all platforms can be created(or reused ) via some commands and then one just needs to do some tweeking around for new platform added .

However i see that when i created my app for android and then i called `cordova platform add ios` command , the code for ios was not auto generated or the same code could not be be reutilised . ie for me now i had to code again .

Question : Was i wrong to assume that this can be done ? can it be done and if yes what are the steps for auto-generating code for a newer platform .

If i have to create code for new platform say ios again from scratch i don't know what benefit does phonegap provides me . ?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap doesnt generate the code for you. I mean, you code in javascript, html and css and you use this code throughout the different platforms. Sometimes, you have to modify it because the calls to internal functionalities can change. But PhoneGap is not a code generator, is not a cross compiler, it´s just a wrapper which embeds your code in a webview and by using the cordova tools, you can generate the skeletons, for every platform, but it wont generate code for you automatically, the code is the one you have made in HTML5. You can take your www folder from iOS and put in in the android skeleton you have created and try it. Sometimes it works from the beginning...and some times, which are the most of the cases, you have to do some fixes to polish the code. Hope it helps